# How to convert PSF represented as a 2D graph into a kernal/convolution matrix?

Tags: matlab, kernel, convolution

My point spread function (PSF) looks like a Sinc wave. How would I convert that into a convolution matrix/kernal similar to that found in the blind deconvolution example found on Mathworks?

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/deblurring-images-using-the-blind-deconvolution-algorithm.html#zmw57dd0e129 (STEP 4)

Please just use a sinc wave as I cannot upload the data points for my PSF.

```
x = -5:.01:5;
plot(x,sinc(x))
```

Kind regards.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] detailing what you have tried so far, why it does not work for you and what you want it to do. We can then try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
x = -5:.05:5;
y = -5:.05:5;

%defines grids that hold x,y values:
[x_grid,y_grid] = meshgrid(x,y);

%.^ notation creates matrix of values sinc(x,y)
m = sinc((x_grid.^2 + y_grid.^2).^(1/2));

surf(m)
shading flat
```